# Live queries trigger only few times

Tags: nginx, parse-platform

I have a strange problem with Parse:
I'm using it in clustering with HTTPS protocols applied with nginx, if I use the not clustered version from a http website all the events from live queries are fired, but from HTTPS and the clustered version only a few times the event is fired, here is my index.js for the server

```
    var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
    var path = require('path');
    var fs = require('fs');

    var api = new ParseServer({
      databaseURI: 'mongodb://' + process.env.MONGO_USER + ':' + process.env.MONGO_$
      cloud: process.env.CLOUD,
      appId: 'appid',
      masterKey: 'master',
      logsFolder: process.env.LOGS,
      maxUploadSize: "128mb",
      verbose: false,
      facebookAppIds: ['fb'],
      oauth: {
        twitter: {
          consumer_key: "ck",
          consumer_secret: "cs",
      }},
      clientKey: 'ck',
      javascriptKey: 'jk',
      restKey: 'rk',
      publicServerURL: process.env.PUBLIC_URL,
      serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
      liveQuery: {
        classNames: ["Notification", "ChatMessage", "Chat"]
      }});
      var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '200mb'}));
api.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '200mb', extended: true}));
api.use(bodyParser.raw({limit: '200mb'}));

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use('/parse', api);
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('Server Running ..');
});

var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(process.env.PORT, function() {
  console.log('We are rocking, baby');
});

ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

and that's my nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    sec;
    return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xxx.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com-0001/fullchain.pem$
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.com-0001/privkey.p$
    client_max_body_size 200M;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;

# Web Socket
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

    location '/.well-known/acme-challenge' {
        default_type "text/plain";
        root /var/www/xxxy;
    }

}
```

any suggestion would be very appreciated 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

find out the solution:
if you have a clustered server you must use redis to cache all the live query event, because if not you'll be always listening only on the cluster you are connected to, which seems not to care about the events in the other clusters